# MySQL syntax error when trying to upload thru MyPHPAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, webserver

This is my first time trying to upload to my host and I've run into errors which my host support can't offer any suggestions on how to proceed.

I am trying to upload my database.sql file through MyPHPAdmin with my host. I'm running the latest version (8.0.25) of MySQL Workbench on my local computer, and have exported the database to a .sql file. My database is operating as it should on my local machine, no errors with any columns.

When trying to upload through MyPHPAdmin, I get the following error...

```
MySQL said: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`possession_team` = `home_team`),`away_team`,`home_team' at line 99
```

And here is the code from the .sql file which is around that area, from section which builds table named 'plays'.

```
 `no_film` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `def_team` varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`possession_team` = `home_team`),`away_team`,`home_team`)) STORED,
  `yards_from_goal` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`field_position` < 0) then (55 + (55 + `field_position`)) else `field_position` end)) STORED,
  `clock_in_seconds` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (time_to_sec(`clock`)) STORED,
  `home_score_diff` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`home_score_before` - `away_score_before`)) STORED,
  `away_score_diff` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`away_score_before` - `home_score_before`)) STORED,
  `off_score_diff` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`possession_team` = `home_team`),(`home_score_before` - `away_score_before`),(`away_score_before` - `home_score_before`))) STORED,
  `def_score_diff` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`possession_team` = `away_team`),(`home_score_before` - `away_score_before`),(`away_score_before` - `home_score_before`))) STORED,
  `st_odk_all` varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`special_teams_type` = 'Kick') then 'KO' when (`special_teams_type` = 'KO') then 'KO' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Punt') then 'P' when (`special_teams_type` = 'PR') then 'P' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Field Goal') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'FGB') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Missed FG') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Convert(1)') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'ConD') then 'FG' else 0 end)) STORED,
  `st_odk_home` varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`special_teams_type` = 'Kick') then 'KO' when (`special_teams_type` = 'KOR') then 'KOR' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Punt') then 'P' when (`special_teams_type` = 'PR') then 'PR' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Field Goal') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'FGB') then 'FGB' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Missed FG') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Convert(1)') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'ConD') then 'FGB' else 0 end)) STORED,
  `st_odk_away` varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`special_teams_type` = 'Kick') then 'KOR' when (`special_teams_type` = 'KOR') then 'KO' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Punt') then 'PR' when (`special_teams_type` = 'PR') then 'P' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Field Goal') then 'FGB' when (`special_teams_type` = 'FGB') then 'FG' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Missed FG') then 'FGB' when (`special_teams_type` = 'Convert(1)') then 'FGB' when (`special_teams_type` = 'ConD') then 'FG' else 0 end)) STORED,
  `d&d` varchar(15) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when ((`down` = '1') and (`distance` = '10') and (`series_number` = '1')) then 'P & 10' when ((`down` = '1') and (`distance` = '10') and (`series_number` <> '1')) then '1ST & 10' when ((`down` = '1') and (`distance` > '10') and (`series_number` <> '1')) then '1ST & 11+' when ((`down` = '1') and (`distance` < '10') and (`series_number` <> '1')) then '1ST & 1-9' when ((`down` = '1') and (`distance` < '10') and (`series_number` = '1')) then 'P & 1-9' when ((`down` = '2') and (`distance` > '10')) then '2ND & XL' when ((`down` = '2') and (`distance` between 8 and 10)) then '2ND & LONG' when ((`down` = '2') and (`distance` between 4 and 7)) then '2ND & MED' when ((`down` = '2') and (`distance` between 1 and 3)) then '2ND & SHORT' when ((`down` = '3') and (`distance` between 1 and 2)) then '3RD & SHORT' when ((`down` = '3') and (`distance` > '2')) then '3RD & LONG' when (((`down` = '0') and (`distance` <> '0') and (`run_pass` = 'R')) or (`run_pass` = 'P')) then '2 PT PLAY' else 0 end)) STORED,
  `fieldzone` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`field_position` between -(1) and -(15)) then 'BACKED UP' when (`field_position` between -(39) and -(16)) then 'OWN FIELD' when ((`field_position` between -(55) and -(40)) or (`field_position` between 41 and 54)) then 'OPEN FIELD' when (`field_position` between 20 and 40) then 'SCORE ZONE' when (`field_position` between 5 and 20) then 'REDZONE' when (`field_position` between 1 and 4) then 'GOALLINE' else 0 end)) STORED,
  `redzone` varchar(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((case when (`field_position` between 1 and 20) then 'Y' else NULL end)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`play_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=973 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version on your server?

Comment: Not sure which of these you wanted, so including both.... Database server version 5.6.41-84.1, and Webserver Database client version: libmysql 5.6.43.

Comment: I ask about the output of `SELECT VERSION();` query. If your MySQL version is 5.6.41 then it simply does not support generated columns...

Comment: This makes sense now. I'm new to this, and non-compatibility at the server end never even crossed my mind. I guess I have to find a service that is compatible.

Comment: That's a rather old version of MySQL and some hosts may allow you to pick a newer version, so you could at least ask your host for some input as your next step.